# ModuleNotFoundError in Conda environment after installing module

Tags: python-3.x, conda, fastapi, virtual-environment

I opened VSCode through my anaconda environment 'fastAPI'. I am attempting to run a script "main.py" in my VSCode powershell terminal. Directory is "fast-api".

```
PS C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Documents\VSCode\projects\fast-api> python3 main.py
```

This returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'fastapi'"

I was able to run my code yesterday after using

```
pip install fastapi[all]
```

but today my code would not run as if I never installed the module. Import line below.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
```

Today I have tried the following options, seperately of course.

```
pip install fastapi[all]

conda install fastapi[all]

conda install -c conda-forge fastapi
```

To check my environment status, I used the following commands. The first returns my base, R-MINI, and fastAPI environment with a star next to it as expected. fastAPi location is 'C:\Users\James\anaconda3\envs\fastAPI'. **Could this path be the issue?** The second line returns my active packages which includes 'fastapi 0.88.0 pyhd8ed1ab_0 conda-forge'.

```
conda env list

conda list
```

A solution I saw earlier suggested folium installation as well but that changed nothing. Running python 3.9.15. Deleted and installed Anaconda today so I am up to date with my conda distribution as well. My biggest source of confusion is how I was able to run the code last night even though I'm sure I had the same setup. I think the issue is that I'm not running the code in the environment I installed the modules in. I can't seem to fix that myself though if that is the issue. I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem on Ubuntu. I had installed uvicorn through apt, and I couldn't get it to work. I uninstalled uvicorn and then installed it using conda install uvicorn into the environment.